# stack view - explanation

Tags: c++

I'm developing something with the ffmpeg lib and x264.
Actually, I'm debugging x264 lib for Windows.

Debug version doesn't work good. It creates video with gray frames. The same release build crashes. What you see below is the stack view from the Eclipse - Indigo. I didn't strip the simbols... But, I have to admit, I didn't check if they are present or not.

Can someone please explain this zero below x264_cabac_block_residual_8x8() call?

```
ffmpeg_debugging Debug [C/C++ Application]  C:\krmak\workspace\ffmpeg_debugging\Debug\ffmpeg_debugging.exe [772]    
        Thread [5] 0 (Suspended : Container)    
        Thread [4] 0 (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)  
            x264_coeff_last64_sse2() at 0x9999a9    
            x264_cabac_block_residual_8x8() at 0x90f6f7 
            0x0 ==> WHAT DOES THIS MEAN??? Call came from a NULL pointer??
        Thread [3] 0 (Suspended : Container)    
        Thread [2] 0 (Suspended : Container)    
        Thread [1] 0 (Suspended : Container)    
    gdb
```

Comment: By looks of things Something in the `x264_cabac_block_residual_8x8()` could be NULL, which you have either attempted to call or dereference.  Have you tried stepping through or printing out values you use in this function?

Comment: Odd numbered address are also suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most probably means that the stack got corrupt.

Comment: I added some logging and x264_cabac_block_residual_8x8() works fine. It seems that stack went to hell. I guess that explains that zero. Can you give me a hint, how to debug that?

Comment: Visual C can generate code that checks for stack overwrites. Since you've mentioned Eclipse, I guess you're using gcc, so check the documentation for your version on gcc.gnu.org and try to find options that will activate as many as possible run-time checks.